# How to use timestamp and use string of severity?

Tags: c++, boost-log

1. I used official code for sink formatting that succeded

```cpp
    sink.set_formatter    (
        expr::stream
        << "[ "
        << expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp","%H:%M:%S.%f")
        << " - " << severity << " ] "
        << expr::smessage
    )
```

But the ouput is `[%time% - 1 ] %message%`.
And the `severity` is just output as `int`

But I wanted result of `[%time% - debug ] %message%`.

I used `severity_logger_mt<SeverityLevel>` with `Severity` just an enum

---

2. I tried to convert `Severity` myself by supplying sink::set_formatter a function, the complied errors and output is shown in code:

```cpp
void coloring_formatter(const boost::log::record_view& record,
                            boost::log::formatting_ostream& stream)
{

  stream << "["
    /* !!! ERROR !!! with no acceptable convertor for <<   */
    << record[timestamp]    

   /*!!! compile ERROR !!! no matching function call for format_date_time */
   << expr::format_date_time<
                    boost::posix_time::ptime>(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

   /*!!! complied done but with no time stamp output !!!  */
<< boost::log::expressions::format_date_time<
                    boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
             << " - " << type << "] "
             << record[boost::log::expressions::smessage];
    }
```

Could anyone help me with

1. right "timestamp" output in function of `sink::set_formatter`
2. output string of `Severity` instead of `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The code you presented is incomplete. In the formatter expression, `severity` has to be an [attribute keyword](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html#log.detailed.expressions.attr_keywords) for it to extract severity levels from log records. It is not clear what it is in your case, I suspect it may be a constant, which is output into a stream regardless of the actual severity level attached to log records.
2. The `coloring_formatter` function is incorrect as it tries to use *formatter lambda expressions* like `expr::format_date_time` with an actual stream.

You have to understand the difference between a *lambda expression* a.k.a. *lazy expression* (which constructs a function to be called at a later time; when that function is called with a stream, it will perform formatting) and an actual streaming expression, which produces output in the stream as it is being executed. `expr::format_date_time` and other components from `boost::log::expressions` namespace are used to compose lambda expressions for filters and formatters. They cannot be used in actual stream output expressions.

When you call `sink.set_formatter`, you have to provide a function, which will perform log record formatting when called. There are multiple ways to describe that function. One way is to use a lambda expression, like in your case #1, starting with `expr::stream` or `expr::format`. Another way is to write the function from scratch, like in your case #2, but in that function you can no longer use lambda expressions.

You can see Boost.Log examples (for instance, [here](https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/boost-1.70.0/example/basic_usage/main.cpp), [here](https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/boost-1.70.0/example/advanced_usage/main.cpp) or [here](https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/boost-1.70.0/example/keywords/main.cpp)) for how to format date/time and severity levels. The important parts to note about those examples:

- There is an `operator<<` for the severity level type, which performs conversion from the enum to a string.  This operator must be in the same namespace as the enum, otherwise the compiler won't find it and will output the enum as an integer.
- The severity level enum must be used in the logger type as its template parameter. This way you will ensure that log records will have severity levels with the type of the enum.
- The severity level enum must be used in the formatter, where you specify the severity level. When you use `expr::attr`, it must be in the template parameter, when you use a keyword, it must be part of the keyword definition with `BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD`. This will ensure the formatter is able to extract your enum from the log record when the formatter is called.
- When formatting a date/time, `expr::format_date_time` can only be used in a lambda expression. When you write your formatting function from scratch, you have to use [Boost.DateTime](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) or functions like [`strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) to format the timestamp.